# Comparacion de dos fechas en php

Tags: php

estoy tratando de comparar 2 fechas en mi sentencia.. estoy mas que seguro que me debe devolver un registro. pero no se porque la condicion no se cumple... alguna idea?

```
    global $wpdb;

$usuarios = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT m.*, u.user_login
                               FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as m
                               inner join {$wpdb->prefix}users as u
                               where m.meta_key = 'wp-last-login' and m.user_id = 516 and u.id = 516", OBJECT );
$paginas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT p.*
                               FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
                               ", OBJECT );
if ($usuarios) {
    foreach ($usuarios as $u) {
        var_dump($fecha_login = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $u->meta_value));
        foreach ($paginas as $p) {
            $fecha_login = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $u->meta_value);
            $fecha_pagina = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $p->post_modified);
            // echo $fecha_pagina.'=>'.$fecha_login;
            // echo '<br>'.'--------------'.'<br>';
            if($fecha_pagina > $fecha_login) {
                var_dump("entro");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la condición que dices que no se cumple? ¿Por qué no haces un `var_dump($usuarios);` y un `var_dump($paginas);`

Comment: la condicion que no se cumple es el `if($fecha_pagina > $fecha_login) {
                var_dump("entro");
            },` lo demas trae todo bien.. el unico problema es mi comparacion

Comment: y que tal un  `var_dump($fecha_pagina)`  y `var_dump($fecha_login)` para que sepamos de que estamos hablando?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien por que utilizas `gmdate()` que tipo de dato recuperas de la base de datos? Esto nos daría una idea de que esta pasando realmente.

Comment: uso gmdate() para decifrar la fecha.. y lo convierte a un formato en que el usuario pueda entender.. ya que en la base de datos no se guarda como una fecha limpia por asi decirlo... El problema no esta en estirar los datos.. el tema es que no me funciona la comparacion en el if... pues quiero traer un registro en donde la fecha sea mayor a la ultma fecha de acceso de un usuario...

Comment: La fecha login y la fecha pagina es posible que tengan la misma fecha? puedes mostrarnos qué fechas estás comparando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin entrar mucho en detalles te recomiendo que pruebes esto:

```
global $wpdb;

$usuarios = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT m.*, u.user_login
                           FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as m
                           inner join {$wpdb->prefix}users as u
                           where m.meta_key = 'wp-last-login' and m.user_id = 516 
                           and u.id = 516", OBJECT );
$paginas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT p.*
                           FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
                           ", OBJECT );
if ($usuarios) {
    foreach ($usuarios as $u) {
        foreach ($paginas as $p) {
            var_dump("Estoy comparando esto: ".$u->meta_value." con esto: ".$p->post_modified );
            if( $u->meta_value > $p->post_modified ) {
                var_dump("entro y sigo con la vida");
                $fecha_login = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $u->meta_value);
                $fecha_pagina = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $p->post_modified);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que hice es comparar los datos tal y como vienen de la base de datos, sin transformarlo a gmdate, porque recuerda que esas funciones cambian el tipo de datos, de modo que el <, >, >=, <= podrían no aplicar para dicho tipo de datos. Ya una vez hecha la comparación, si todo sale bien puedes usar el gmdate para dejarlo en un formato más humano.

Además, agregué un var_dump que te muestra lo que estas comparando en cada iteración.

Espero aportar